# Jboss 5.1.0: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation for class javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: jboss5.x

I have read quite a lot about this error, the reason are:

1. more than one jar containing this class have been include into the classpath,
2. include the jar twice or more,

but in my case, this class is jdk class, and I have search no this class have been found under my application.

Any clue would be very helpful.

exception stack:

```
2012-10-31 14:09:58,319 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1:) Unexpected error during load of:javax.sql.DataSource
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/sql/DataSource"
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:67)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:633)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:592)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:591)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:568)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:135)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:455)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:267)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:166)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:287)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1163)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:862)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:502)
      at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:447)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
      at com.lombardrisk.webgui.dwr.ajax_search.UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.getBranchesByAgreementId(UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.java:199)
      at com.lombardrisk.webgui.dwr.ajax_search.UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.buildConditionOfPrinAndCpty(UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.java:177)
      at com.lombardrisk.webgui.dwr.ajax_search.UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.getFunds(UmbrellaNettingFundsSearch.java:58)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
      at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
      at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
      at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
      at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
      at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
      at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at com.lombardrisk.webgui.filter.ValidRequestFilter.doFilter(ValidRequestFilter.java:41)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.internalProcess(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:74)
      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:47)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is resolved

there do have another jar(jdbc2_0-stdext.jar) containing this class, and is bring to app by us.

class B is OK because the statment  con = ds.getConnection is call in another  X.jar, whereas class A is called inside it self Y.war,  and this jdbc2_0-stdext.jar is package in Y.war